# Como faço para verificar se um iframe carregou completamente

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Então, eu estou produzindo um site onde estou usando `iframes` com outros sites dentro dele, veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Código:*

```
<iframe width="100%" height="747px" src="www.site.com" id="iPrincipal" scrolling='no' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
```

Mas a questão é que demora alguns segundos pra carregar completamente o iframe/outro site, então queria saber um jeito de identificar se foi totalmente carregado. Como por exemplo, um alerta: 'o iframe foi totalmente carregado'.

Desde já agradeço :)

Comment: Bom,você disse que não funcionou. Primeiro de tudo, aconselho da próxima vez a comentar em minha resposta para evitar problemas. Mas voltando ao assunto, poderia por neste seu post (editando-o) o conteúdo dentro das tags <head> dos respectivos sites? Eu garanto que o código que passei funciona, e seria de grande agrado se pudesse configurar para você.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, basta você por um window.load na página do iframe, tipo isso

Na página onde contém o

```
<iframe src="SeuIframe.html">
```

Coloque o código abaixo dentro da tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function carregado(msg){ alert(msg) }
    </script>
```

Já na página do SeuIframe.html, coloque isso:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            parent.carregado("Página 100% carregado.")
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: bom... não funcionou. Tipo, eu não estou fazendo essa operação entre **arquivos.html** do mesmo site, eu estou usando domínios diferentes, ou seja: são dois sites. Digamos que eu tenha um site principal: www.siteprincipal.com! E claro, o iframe vai "reproduzir" o outro site: www.outrosite.com, entendeu? kk Acho que essa verificação que eu estou tentando fazer é impossível, o único jeito seria colocar um texto "Carregando iframe..." e fazer ele aparecer depois de um determinado tempo (usando um timer e a função style.display)